# Do I need Express to create web services using Nextjs?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

I am trying to create a general web service using Nextjs.
In my research, I often see cases where Express is used as the backend for Nextjs.

However, Nextjs has an api function.
In what cases do we need to use Express for the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't really need *Express* as the backend server. You should be able to use any framework from any programming language. I guess the reason that you often see it used is because it is the best [documented](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#nodejs-server).

Regarding api routes, you will always have to use some kind of backend server as it does [not work](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction#caveats) with `next export` (aka creating a static folder containing *html*, *css* and *JavaScript*).